# Graphs, Tiling and topological equivalence

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.$  I am fully aware that no subset of the plane it topologically equivalent to a torus.  However, it seems to require a lot of heavy machinery to prove this.  Does it more simply follow from the fact that I can tile a torus with something like $K_5$ and the graph $K_5$ is not planar.

That is, suppose that $X$ is topologically equivalent to a torus.  Then any tiling of a Torus is a tiling of $X$.  Let $\tau$ be a tiling of the torus with $K_5$.  Then $\tau$ is also a tiling of $X$.  But, we know that $g(K_5)=1>0.$  Hence $K_5$ cannot tile the plane.  Thus they are not topologically equivalent.